# Realtek 8513 USB Support

Tags: usb

Bug?  All information I can find claims that Realtek 8513 is supported in Ubuntu 20.04 yet my USB adapter is dead.

Any ideas?  Here is lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: 8513 or 8153? Please modify accordingly.

Comment: Your device is claimed by two possibly conflicting drivers, *cdc_ether* and *r8152*. Which is loaded? `lsmod | grep -e cdc -e r8152`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't even understand what this  means:
tbb01@NHLaptop:~/Desktop$ lsmod | grep -e cdc -e r8152
cdc_ether              20480  0
usbnet                 45056  1 cdc_ether
r8152                  69632  0
mii                    20480  2 usbnet,r8152  Indeed, which is loaded?  The only USB device that IS plugged in is a USB dongle with the RTL8513.

Comment: So, indeed there are TWO drivers.  What do I do now?

Comment: Please see my answer that I will post in a few moments.

Comment: This had no effect for me. What almost always works in unplugging it (the usb-network interface) and plugging it back in. I've tried using 'usbreset' from the command line, but it doesn't work. My version of this is usb-c. does anyone know if there is another way to reset usb[c]?

Answer (score 1):

As we see from your listing of loaded modules (`lsmod`), there are two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. Let's blacklist one and see if there is any improvement. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist cdc_ether" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and check:

```
ip addr show
dmesg | grep 815
```

Comment: I need to plead guilty to an engineering crime:. I changed two things at once.

Comment: I changed to a new laptop & OS AND I changed to a new (Usb-C) ethernet adapter.  The USB adapter turns out to be faulty.

Comment: I replaced it and all is well

Comment: I'm glad it's working by whatever means. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with USB-C dock and also with monitor dock featuring RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter. It was caused by aggressive power-saving of TLP. Making TLP to exclude this device from being auto-suspended helped.

In my case, it's listed in `lsusb` as:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
```

To prevent TLP from auto-suspending it, add following to `/etc/tlp.conf`:

```
USB_BLACKLIST="0bda:8153"
```

This option was renamed to `USB_DENYLIST` in version `1.4` of TLP - in newer Ubuntu versions than 20.04.

> This parameter was renamed with version 1.4. In 1.3.1 and below it is called USB_BLACKLIST. 1.4 and higher also recognize the old name.